# Flutter: Firebase Firestore custom sync rules

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, offline

Right now I have a Flutter project which uses version 2.10.4 and I also have Firebase configured to be able to use Firestore and I have offline use enabled so that when my app can access the internet the data is synchronized. I would like to know if it is possible to create some rules for this synchronization, for example that they are executed in a specific order, or in the order that they were added to that queue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore's offline persistence functions as a cache, not as a synchronization mechanism. Items are added to the cache in the order in which you read them, and when needed are expunged from least recently used to most recently used.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for r answer, so, isn't possible setting the cache push to cloud interval, for example?

Comment: The cache is not controllable beyond what I said above. It is not a synchronization mechanism, so there's no concept of an interval.